# Document Folder Structure Template

Tags: template

I am new in Sharepoint 2013 and Our Company has multiple projects (jobs) and I am trying to create folder structure template with folders inside, how can I do this?
I have created for a subsite call projects:
I have created a document library for each location eg (L-Location)
Inside each location the idea is to set up template as we have to label (L-001) to (L-XXX) 
and I have read that Im not able to create a Document library inside other documemt library.. any help???Ideas

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document Set content type fits your needs reasonably well. The only issue is that you cannot create empty folders in it, but if each of your folders contains at least one (empty) template document, it will work for you.

You basically need to complete the following steps:

1. Enable the Site Collection Feature 'Document Sets' (Settings / Site Collection Features)
2. Create a new Content Type with parent 'Document Set' and create your folder structure by adding Default Content
3. Enable a document library to use this new Content Type

If you need a more detailed explanation, please let me know,

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you!, I have tried but yes If you don't mind giving me detailed explanation, would be great!!

Comment: Hi @Robert, i  followed the steps you mentioned but it is not working, could you please gives us detail steps.

Comment: Hi @G.Srinivas, I guess the first two steps are clear? I'll make more detailed steps for 'enabling a document library' to use this new content type. If the first two steps arent clear either, let me know!